# jQuery setTimeout $this.remove() Overlapping for Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I have 2 separate `<div>` elements that have a similar `invoke` button which adds a transparent overlay message. My issue is that when I click both buttons in rapid succession, or the same button twice before the timeout expires, the overlay is only removed once (instead of stacking with however many overlays are added). I would appreciate any help in solving this problem, as well as if someone can help me tidy up my code (it seems grossly inefficient).

> JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/733ueao4/

```
$(document).on('click', '#invoke', function(e) {

    $this = $(this);

    $cardOverlay = $("<div style='transition: background 0.2s linear' class='card-overlay'><span style='color:white;position:relative;top:40%;font-weight:bold'>Success!</span></div>");

    $this.parent('.card-shadow').append($cardOverlay);

    $cardOverlay.height('100%').css({
        'opacity' : 1,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
        'width': '100%',
        'z-index': 1,
        'border-radius': '6px',
        'text-align': 'center'
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $cardOverlay.fadeOut("normal", function(){
            $(this).remove();
        })
    }, 2000)
});
```

Comment: Just adding var to `$this` and `$cardOverlay`. Also, the id should be unique, so you may use a class or attr to trigger your action. Like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/fb9b1ne3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot `var` before `$cardOverlay`, therefore `$cardOverlay` is defined in the global scope and is the *same* variable for every time your handler runs. You're overwriting its value each time you click on `#invoke` which means when the `setTimeout` runs, it always refers to the newest assignment to `$cardOverlay` and so the reference to the old overlay is lost. Change:

```
$cardOverlay = $("<div style='transition: background 0.2s linear' class='card-overlay'><span style='color:white;position:relative;top:40%;font-weight:bold'>Success!</span></div>");
```

to

```
var $cardOverlay = $("<div style='transition: background 0.2s linear' class='card-overlay'><span style='color:white;position:relative;top:40%;font-weight:bold'>Success!</span></div>");
```

For similar reasons, you also probably want to add `var` before `$this = $(this);` as well. Remember, although you're allowed to omit `var` in javascript, each time you do the variable is defined in the global scope, and other methods can come along (or the same method could run a second time) and interfere with the values of your variables. Generally speaking if you are using a variable that you only want to have access to within a certain scope, you should define it with `var` in that scope, which in your case is your handler function.

Comment: Awesome! Can't believe I missed that.Gave you the Check, any chance you have any suggestions to make the code more readable/efficient? It looks quite ugly as is.

Comment: @Hybrid I would ditch the dollar signs, and instead of `$this` use `self`